# What is the correct way to create a django form?

Tags: python, django

Could you please advice on the best way to create a view, in the latest version of django?

I am creating my views this way:

```
def create_issue(request, chantier_id):
    issue = get_object_or_404(Issue, pk=issue_id)
    form = IssueForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        issue = form.save(commit=False)
        issue.save()   
    return render(request, 'chantiers/detail.html', {'chantier': chantier})
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, 'chantiers/create_issue.html', context)
```

and I know we can also use some View:

```
class EstimateCreateView(AbstractSaleCreateUpdateMixin,
                         generic.CreateView):
    template_name = "accounts/bill_create_or_update.html"
    model = Estimate
    form_class = EstimateForm
    formset_class = EstimateLineFormSet
    success_url = reverse_lazy("accounts:estimate-list")
```

Many Thanks,

Comment: Have you read [the official documentation on creating forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django)?

Comment: both class base and function base view are ok to use. if you are a beginner than go with function base view as you will understand the flow of the code and know what the code is doing.

Comment: Thank you, I was just not sure if I was following an older way of creating view based on the different version of django.